# Design a class, what's wrong if using IList as type of property?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

I have a simple class below, it has a property `Pages` of type IList.

There are some options to implement this property, it can be an `Array` or a `Collection` / `List` / even `ReadOnlyCollection`

```
public class Book
    {
        private string[] _pages;

        public Book(string[] pages)
        {
            _pages = pages;
        }

        public IList<string> Pages
        {
            get
            {
                return _pages;
                //return new Collection<string>(_pages);
                //return new List<string>(_pages);
                //return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(_pages);
            }
        }
    }
```

**At design time**, I do not know which actions that its clients will use the property but choosing any option above will affect its clients.

If a client uses `Book` class as below

```
var book = new Book(new[] {"A", "B"});
var pages = book.Pages;
pages[0] = "A2";
```

Not all implementation options of the property `Pages` will work for the client.

Option 1: returning an Array for Pages `// OK, it works`

```
public IList<string> Pages
    {
        get
        {
            return _pages;
        }
    }
```

Option 2: returning a Collection for Pages `// KO, it throws an exception NotSupportedException Collection is read-only`

```
public IList<string> Pages
    {
        get
        {
            return new Collection<string>(_pages);
        }
    }
```

Option 3: returning a List for Pages `// OK, it works`

```
public IList<string> Pages
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<string>(_pages);
        }
    }
```

Option 4: returning a ReadOnlyCollection for Pages `// KO, it throws an exception SystemException Collection is read-only`

```
public IList<string> Pages
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(_pages);
        }
    }
```

I don't think it could be wrong on the client side. Could anyone please give some explanation and suggest a good type for the `Page`?

Comment: What are you trying to do with what you return will tell you the best option to use. You also can't have a readonly string[] pages if you want to be able to edit the pages later.  Remove the readonly and it should work fine.

Comment: It's unclear to me the use of the `pages` property. Maybe you should provide more context. Are you representing the contents of each page of the book as a `string`? If so, what exactly do you want your users to do with a `Book`?

Comment: If you were coding using Test Driven Development, then you would have no code at all except for the code that was necessary to make a failing unit test pass (and compile). Would you have written a unit test to enumerate the `Pages` property? Then it has to be at least `IEnumerable<string>`. Would you have written a unit test which indexes into the sequence of strings? Then it has to be at least `IReadOnlyCollection<string>`, etc. Not until you have a unit test that adds a page to the collection would you need the type of the property to be `IList<string>`.

Comment: Please explain why, in addition to the property, the `_pages` field and the constructor's `pages` parameter are not simply also declared as having the type `IList<string>`. As stated, your question is very hard to understand what exactly it is you're asking.

Comment: @WHermann thanks for the information. I just want to provide a list of pages to clients of Book class. At client side, it can replace a page in the list.

Comment: @JohnSaunders yes, exactly I write some tests for the Book. I think the List<string> can be good, but I should use interface instead of concrete type.

Comment: Use the least specific type that works. Would `IEnumerable<string>` work? Then use it. No? Maybe `IReadOnlyCollection<string>`. Keep going from the most general type to the most specific type.

Comment: @PeterDuniho the IList interface provide ability to add/replace an element in the list, so it's generic to be used. But some further readings give me this try to use different implementation (for the IList). So with each one, it affects to client but I think it shouldn't.

Comment: If you don't explain in precise detail what _doesn't_ work, no one can with any certainty offer an answer to explain what _will_ work.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I've updated, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to define your own collection type `PageCollection` for example and use it in your `Book` class. The advantage of this is, that you hide the detail of how the collection is implemented. Another advantage of this approach is, that you can provide "special" methods for the collection.

For example you could extend an existing collection (it may also be a good advise to create a custom class for `Page`, instead of using plain strings:

```
public class PageCollection : List<Page>
{
    // additional methods
}
```

You can also wrap an existing collection. This has the advantage that you have full controll over the methods you want to provide to the "user".

```
public class PageCollection : IEnumerable<Page>
{
    private List<Page> _innerCollection = new List<Page>();

    public void RipOut(IEnumerable<Page> pages)
    {
        foreach (var page in pages)
        {
            _innerCollection.Remove(page);
        }
    }

    // other methods

    public IEnumerator<Page> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _innerCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I should have Page class also. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you are asking: How do I design a class without knowing how it will be used?

The answer is, design it by putting in the functionality you want to support.

**In your example:**
You have a book with pages. Would you like the user to be able to go to page 0, rip it out, and replace it with something else? If so, make it a List. If not, make it a ReadOnlyCollection.

I would recommend exposing the property as what it actually is (List or ReadOnlyCollection), that way you give clear intent into what is allowed and don't have the client guessing if they can or cannot replace the page.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion @hatcyl. The IList provides what I need, loop through all items, add, remove. But using different concrete types "Array or a Collection / List / even ReadOnlyCollection" can break its client code. So the IList behaviors are not working in the same manner on different implementation.

Answer (score 1):

So finally I come with this design. The custom `PageCollection` has Add/Remove methods will allow me to add validation behavior inside. If using the `List<Page>`, this is not possible.

The Book now exposes `IPageCollection` Pages which has less methods than the IList.

**Updated:** Below are reasons to create the new interface:

- IList / List is not conform in this situation because it's a little fat as some one said already.
- List does not allow to have custom validation on Add / Remove a page from the list
- Using a generic list does not satisfy [a Code Analysis rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CA1002);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true)
- If needed other methods like AddRange, Clear... it's easy to implement

.

```
public class Page
{
}

public interface IPageCollection : IReadOnlyList<Page>
{
    void Add(Page page);
    void Remove(Page page);
}

public class PageCollection : IPageCollection
{
    public PageCollection(IList<Page> pages)
        : base(pages)
    {
    }

    public void Add(Page page)
    {
    }

    public void Remove(Page page)
    {
    }

    ...
}

public class Book
{
    private readonly PageCollection _pages;

    public Book(IList<Page> pages)
    {
        _pages = new PageCollection(pages);
    }

    public IPageCollection Pages
    {
        get { return _pages; }
    }
}
```

(thanks for suggestions from guys John, Thomas...)

Comment: I am compelled to ask why your interface derives from ReadOnlyList<Page> if the user can add and remove items from it. These seem to be contradictory constraints, and only make the interface confusing. Further, they tie the hands of potential consumers. For example, as PageCollection is written, I wouldn't be able to do an AddRange, Clear, or other bulk operations.

Comment: @MikeHofer The AddRange and Clear... methods and some others from the List are nice to have. But List can't be used because some validation is needed before add/remove. One other point I found on MSDN to not "Do not expose generic lists" https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CA1002);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true